# How do i use layer_get_unobstructed_bounds?

Tags: c, pebble-watch, cloudpebble

i want to implement `layer_get_unobstructed_bounds()` but it doesn't work for me.
When i run the app it prints every second `-50` and QuickView doesn't change that. What am i doing wrong?
In conclusion: `layer_get_unobstructed_bounds()` doesn't change at all.

Here is my code: https://github.com/WuerfelDev/LIFT/tree/test

The `printf` is at line 33

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My fault was that i used `origin.y` instead `size.h`.
I thought it would return the QuickViews bounds, but instead it actually represents the bounds of the part of the screen **where the QuickView is not shown**.

---

Big thanks to @PebbleDev on twitter:

https://twitter.com/PebbleDev/status/771372057590390784